# Check if a patteren contains more than. one string( type array)

Tags: perl, pattern-matching

How to check if a pattern is an array( contains more than one string) or just a single string?

Consider the following example,

```
If ( $_ =~ /#define\s+(\S+)\s*(.*)/gi )

.. 
#Check if $2 is array or a single string 
If ( $2
```

If it's array than split them into patterns else keep it as it ?

Please suggest.

Regards, Div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few basic rules and terminology. A regex match is done on a string, which is in a single-valued variable, a *scalar*.  An *array* variable is associated with a collection of items,  representing a *list* of values. Perhaps you can start with [Perl-variable-types](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Perl-variable-types) in [perlintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html), and for regex with [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

In the example you show, the variable `$_` contains the string to be checked for the pattern.

The match operator returns a list of matches captured by the parentheses in the pattern. With `/g` modifier the behavior is more complex, and it depends on whether the regex is used in scalar or list *context*. See this under [Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).  In short, assign that list of matches to an array (no need for `/g` then)

```
my @matches = $_ =~ /#define\s+(\S+)\s*(.*)/i;
```

and you can check the number of elements in the array

```
if (@matches == 0) {
    print "There were no matches\n";
}
elsif (@matches == 1) {
    print "Found one match: $matches[0]\n";
}
else {
    print "Found more than one: @matches\n";
}
```

Another way to check for an empty array is `if (not @matches)`.

This captures a word `\S+` and a (possible) remainder of the line `.*`, when preceded by `#define` with some space. Note that the regex allows this to come anywhere in the string. If, in fact, it must be at the beginning then add the anchor with optional space at the beginning, `/^\s*.../`

Comment: @divesh-rastogi I updated a little, in particular rephrased the comments on `/g` and added a description of the regex. You may want to look over it again.  I'd suggest to read up on basics -- it won't take long at all but will make life far easier and nicer :).  Thank you for the attribution.